# How to store a List of a class object into MySql using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to store a List of class : RestApiResponse into MySql. But getting below error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: com.try.sreapi.beans.RestApiResponse
```

Below are my classes:

Entity class : SREAPITestingHistory.java

```
    @NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="getSREAPITestHistory.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM SREAPITestingHistory a"))

@SqlResultSetMapping(name="sreapitestinghistoryres",
entities=@EntityResult(entityClass=SREAPITestingHistory.class))

@Entity
@Table(name="sreapi_testing_history_details")
@Transactional
public class SREAPITestingHistory implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7221709766109001257L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="request_time")
    private String request_time;
    
    @Column(name="req_id")
    private String req_id;
    
    @Column(name="app_name")
    private String app_name; 
    
    @Column(name="request_name")
    private String request_name;
    
    @Lob
    @Column(name="response_body")
    private List<RestApiResponse> response;

    public String getRequest_time() {
        return request_time;
    }

    public void setRequest_time(String request_time) {
        this.request_time = request_time;
    }

    public String getReq_id() {
        return req_id;
    }

    public void setReq_id(String req_id) {
        this.req_id = req_id;
    }

    public String getApp_name() {
        return app_name;
    }

    public void setApp_name(String app_name) {
        this.app_name = app_name;
    }


    public String getRequest_name() {
        return request_name;
    }

    public void setRequest_name(String request_name) {
        this.request_name = request_name;
    }

    public List<RestApiResponse> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(List<RestApiResponse> response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    
}
```

Repository Class: SREAPITestingRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface SREAPITestingRepository extends CrudRepository< SREAPITestingHistory, String> {
    
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="INSERT into sreapi_testing_history_details (request_time,req_id,app_name,request_name,response_body)"+ "VALUES (:request_time,:req_id,:app_name,:request_name,:response_body)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void setApiTestHistoryDetails(@Param("request_time") String request_time,@Param("req_id") String req_id,@Param("app_name") String app_name,@Param("request_name") String request_name,@Param("response_body") List<RestApiResponse> response_body);

}
```

When I am trying to add values for response_body which is actually a List of RestApiResponse class and I am getting Could not determine a type for class: com.try.sreapi.beans.RestApiResponse exception

Comment: your enitity is named `SREAPITestingHistory`, whereas your repository is looking for `SREAPITesting`. And for a list of entities, you have the option of `.saveAll()`, why not use that?

Comment: The issue is with the class object. If I use .saveAll() then also this error was coming.

Comment: @NamanAgarwal Did you check the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

From Official [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html)

> **A Lob may be either a binary or character type.**
>
> The Lob type is inferred from the type of the persistent field or
> property, and except for string and character-based types defaults to
> Blob.
>
> Example 1:
>
> @Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)    @Column(name="REPORT")
> String report;
>
> Example 2:
>
> @Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)    @Column(name="EMP_PIC",
> columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")    protected byte[] pic;

So you can convert your list of data into json string or bytes to store.